# How to merge patches

Tags: command-line

Sometimes I need to merge two patches. I can apply them but often it is not convenient (coping, temporary files etc.). Is there a tool to merge patches (assuming they are not conflicting)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you manage patches often, then you may be interested in `quilt`. I believe it has a patch combination feature.

See [Quilt (software)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quilt_%28software%29) for more info.

Comment: And something that does not require sources?

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in maintaining the source, you could put it into a version control system, add patches to it, and get the patches you want out of it.

Comment: I do it mainly for backporting patches. I tend to do it with version control system but I wondered if there is easier way.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka, your best bet is to use the tools of your VCS, or tools specifically built for it. Perhaps you should look into a more modern VCS for your work, like [mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org) or [git](https://git-scm.com). As far as I know, both have capable tools to import and otherwise interact with legacy VCS.