# How to split and edit patches?

Tags: vim, patch

Sometimes I need to split a big patch into smaller (disjoint) ones, e.g. for every separate feature included.

Usually I do it via standard vim yank/dd commands and split-window switching.

But are there some tools/vim-tricks to help with such kind of editing?

For example support for commands like: move the 3  next complete hunks to right opened patch file

Comment: You may want to also look on http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/618/how-to-merge-patches

Comment: BTW, how come that people answer the question but do not find it useful/clear enough to up-vote it ?!? ;)

Answer (score 7):

You might want to take a look into patchutils [1]. For the vim part, I wrote a small vim plugin that helps with navigating in patches: diff_navigator [2].

[1] http://cyberelk.net/tim/software/patchutils/

[2] http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2361

Comment: The `diff_navigator` URL is apparently http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2361  Emacs has similar features in the [Ediff](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/emacs_342.html) and SMerge modes

Comment: Could you extend your answer to make it more comprehensive? Adding an example how to use what utility from the patchutils set to split a big patch into disjoint ones would be great ...

Answer (score 5):

Somewhat off-topic, I guess but I still think it's useful.

If you use git to do your development you can easily split your whole changes into smaller "hunks" that embody one feature each. You end up with one commit per feature and can use git's `git-format-patch` to create (and even sign and properly attribute) patches, I outlined how to do that [here](http://the-gay-bar.com/2009/02/10/git-tricks-commiting-only-certain-changes-from-one-file/)

Answer (score 4):

My Suse has `splitdiff` util which works like this:

```
$ splitdiff -a tmp.179639.patch
Wrote >tmp.179639.patch.part001
Wrote >tmp.179639.patch.part002
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://www.clearchain.com/blog/posts/splitting-a-patch) to split the big patch to smaller chunks (either per file or every hunk) and then if you need to merge then use combinediff from the [patchutils](http://cyberelk.net/tim/software/patchutils/) package that was mentioned in [Petr Uzel's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2580/8299)